# Simplifying an image in matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I have a picture of a handwritten letter (say the letter, "y"). Keeping only the first of the three color values (since it is a grayscale image), I get a 111x81 matrix which I call aLetter. I can see this image (please ignore the title) using:

colormap gray; image(aLetter,'CDataMapping','scaled')

[image: Picture of handwritten letter]

What I want is to remove the white space around this letter and somehow average the remaining pixels so that I have an 8x8 matrix (let's call it simpleALetter). Now if I use:

colormap gray; image(simpleALetter,'CDataMapping','scaled')

I should see a pixellated version of the letter:

[image: pixellated version of the handwritten letter]

Any advice on how to do this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need several steps to achieve what you want (updated in the light of @rwong's observation that I had white and black flipped…):

1. Find the approximate 'bounding box' of the letter:

   - make sure that "text" is the highest value in the image
   - set things that are "not text" to zero - anything below a threshold
   - sum along row and column, find non-zero pixels
2. upsample the image in the bounding box to a multiple of 8
3. downsample to 8x8

Here is how you might do that with your situation

```
aLetter = max(aLetter(:)) - aLetter; % invert image: now white = close to zero
aLetter = aLetter - min(aLetter(:)); % make the smallest value zero
maxA = max(aLetter(:));
aLetter(aLetter < 0.1 * maxA) = 0; % thresholding; play with this to set "white" to zero

% find the bounding box:
rowsum = sum(aLetter, 1);
colsum = sum(aLetter, 2);
nonzeroH = find(rowsum);
nonzeroV = find(colsum);
smallerLetter = aLetter(nonzeroV(1):nonzeroV(end), nonzeroH(1):nonzeroH(end));

% now we have the box, but it's not 8x8 yet. Resampling:
sz = size(smallerLetter);

% first upsample in both X and Y by a factor 8:
bigLetter = repmat(reshape(smallerLetter, [1 sz(1) 1 sz(2)]), [8 1 8 1]);
% then reshape and sum so you end up with 8x8 in the final matrix:
letter8 = squeeze(sum(sum(reshape(bigLetter, [sz(1) 8 sz(2) 8]), 3), 1));

% finally, flip it back "the right way" black is black and white is white:
letter8 = 255 - (letter8 * 255 / max(letter8(:)));
```

You can do this with explicit `for` loops but it would be much slower.

You can also use some of the `blockproc` functions in Matlab but I am using Freemat tonight and it doesn't have those… Neither does it have any image processing toolbox functions, so this is "hard core".

As for picking a good threshold: if you know that > 90% of your image is "white", you could determine the correct threshold by sorting the pixels and finding the threshold dynamically - as I mentioned in my comment in the code "play with it" until you find something that works in your situation.

Comment: The code seems to be treating white background as non-zero.

Comment: @rwong - you may be right. I come from a background where "white = 0", but if "white = 1" you need to invert the logic of the first few lines.

Comment: white background has the value 255

Comment: In case you already have Image Processing Toolbox, the last resampling  step can be done with `imresize`.

Comment: "Thresholding" is the correct word, and deserves to be mentioned in the steps outline. Note that there are more intelligent thresholding algorithms tailored for pen stroke detection, so you may want to use those instead of hard-coded threshold value.

Comment: I have updated my answer - it now should have black and white the right way around...

Comment: Thank you, both of you. Is there a way for me to thank rwong also and give him karma points or something (not entirely familiar with this website)? aLetter(aLetter < 0.5 * maxA) = 0 seems to give me the closest to what I want. I will have to keep experimenting with threshold values since some of the squares that I know should be light gray are barely visible.

Comment: @ilikecats - I don't think there is a way to give someone who made a valuable comment "karma"; but I am sure that a heartfelt "thank you" like yours is worth more than a few reputation points. Come back often, and answer questions where your expertise allows - that's the best way to say thanks.